# How to check A4J connections status?

Tags: jquery, ajax, selenium, python-3.x

i have a little problem with testcase creation.
The environment is:

- Selenium IDE
- Python 3.4
- Test-Site with A4J 3.3.3 (a4j/g/3_3_3.Final/org/ajax4jsf/framework.pack.js)

Test-Case:

> 1 Start clock
>
> 2 Click on 'Open Document List'
>
> 3 Wait for loading
>       (here is the problem-point)
>
> 4 Stop clock

The problem is in the point 3.
I have no parameters i can check for visibility after doc-list-loading.
If there is no documents in the clicked 'open Documen List' the page after loading will have no changes.
So i must check ajax connections activity and go to point 4 only after all ajax connections are closed.
Question: How can i make this check. I'm a complete noob in JS and AJAX.
I've tried 'jQuery.active' - returns 0 , a4j:status returns an error: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Here is my function in python:

`def ajax_complete(self, driver):
        js_condition = 'alert(a4j:status)'
        try:
            driver.execute_script(js_condition)
            #return 0 == driver.execute_script(js_condition)
        except WebDriverException:
            <ba bla -bla>`

I would be very happy to have your help.
(I can't give you the testpage link, it is only intranet )

Comment: Sorry for no greetings, the system will not accept my "Hello guys", "Hello @all" .. :-(

Comment: No greetings are necessary. On SO we prefer to get straight to the heart of the matter. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve